# EmberJs: Update the Data Store Schema

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently developing an Ember application and I've come across a blocker...
I am loading my data from a RESTful api and this was working a treat, but I have now updated one of my models with 2 new fields.  The server is returning the new json format and it includes the new field. DS.Model consumed by the ember application also contains the new fields but when I view the Data in the chrome plugin, the schema does not seem to reflect the changes to the model.  I have tried clearing the cache in the browser but it does not seem to force the schema to update.
Any pointers?

Comment: Can you post your load code in a jsfiddle or similar?  Difficult to say what the issue is without it

Comment: The project is a little too large to upload to jsfiddle, I am getting the impression that the schema should automatically update when the js model changes, is my assumption correct?

Comment: It depends.  There seem to be instances where, if you have certain data within your model, it doesn't display the schema correctly.  For example, in one of my models I have a json object stored in one of the fields.  However, in the schema, it doesn't show any field after that object.

Comment: The fields I had added were just a number and string field so it should have worked.  Check my answer below.  I will do some more digging but I'm hoping its just an issue with the chrome plugin.

Comment: Ok confirmed, this is definitely a bug in the chrome plugin.  You see all the data when you click on the row but the table view does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have done a bit more digging and it seems to be an issue with the Chrome plugin

The datagrid view does not display the new columns but if you drill into the rows then the attributes ARE being shown, this has at least pointed me in the correct direction.